# Accessory Navicular Syndrome Revovery Without Surgery

Tags: injury

I have an accessory navicular bone on both my feet. I sprained my left ankle mildly three months ago and also started to get another pain at the the inside of my foot (at the point of accessory navicular). After visiting the ortho, he said that I have the accessory navicular syndrome and the symptoms came out after the foot injury.

I tried to return to jogging after 4 weeks rest twice but the pain on the inside foot comes back. Upon doctor's advice I have been wearing an insoul with arch support for last 4 weeks without any sports. He said to give it 3 months and then if it doesn't work then they'll do a procedure to remove the bone. Almost one month has passed since that and I feel the progress is very very slow if any.

I've read on the forums and virtually found no one who had the pain totally fix with non-surgical treatment. I don't want to waste 3 months and then find out that operation is needed to return to sport and then spend a further lengthy recovery time.

If surgery is the only reliable option, I want to go for it sooner. Is there anyone who had the symptoms fixed without a non-surgical treatment and returned to full action in running or sports?

Comment: Consulting the Internet is no substitute for consulting a doctor. We know nothing about you or your foot, and we can't see it unless you provide imagery. Preferably x-rays. But then again, if you get x-rays, you may as well ask the doctor while you're there.

Comment: I already consulted the doctor with x-rays. And I trust his judgement.

Only wanted to find out if someone with sports background was able to fully recover without surgery. I guess I get your point, I'm just being too anxious :(